# When default destructor is enough for the class?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Let's say we have three classes: Parent, Child and Other.

```
class Parent: {
public:
    Parent(std::string title): m_title(title) { }
    void setTitle (std::string title);
private:
    std::string m_title;
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    Child(std::string title) { setTitle(title); }
private:
    Other object;
};

class Other {
public:
    Other() : m_body("") { }
    std::string body();
    void setBody(std::string);
private:
    std::string m_body;
};
```

Is it OK to use default destructors for all of these classes?

My point is, since I'm not allocating any memory manually, I don't need to care about its deallocation.

The Big Question: Is there a general rule when default destructor is enough?

Comment: If you explicitly create or allocate anything in a constructor, you need to destroy or free it in a destructor. In your examples, you don't do that so here no destructor is needed.

Comment: Oh by the way, in the `Child` class, you could use an initializer list for its constructor as well: `Child(std::string title) : Parent(title) {}`

Comment: From memory allocation point of view there is no need to define a constructor.

Comment: See the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). If it applies, chances are that the default constructor won't suffice either.

Comment: Another issues with this code: 1. it is better to use explicit keyword to prevent implicitly created Child from string; 2. it is better to use  const references for complex arguments instead of value-argument (setBody(const std::string&)) to prevent needless coping of the string; 3. If you delete Child via pointer to parent class you will have a memory leak because destructor of Child will not called (compiler don't known anything about Child in this case) - you should use virtual dtor in base class.

Comment: 4. It is better to return const std::string& from Other::body method to prevent needless copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a virtual destructor for `Parent`, but the body of the destructor would be defaulted in C++11 or empty. It's still a default destructor, but you need to explicitly define it so that it is possible to `delete` `Child` through a pointer to `Parent`.

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    // virtual ~Parent() {} //
    // ...
};
```

Without considering polymorphism you only need to define a destructor when the class needs to do something extra on destruction. For example the class may need to deallocate manually managed resources or unregister from somewhere. Another special case is a scope guard whose only purpose is to do something on destruction.

Almost all of the classes I make only have default destructor. When I see an explicit destructor definition I begin being suspicious.

Comment: @NeilKirk: True, I didn't notice the inheritance at first.

Comment: So in C++ it's a better practice to design the class in such way that destructor won't be necessary? (except for virtual destructors in ancestor classes)

Comment: @VasilyZhovner: Exactly, that is my point. Actually designing classes to not require an explicit destructor is much easier than doing otherwise especially when there is more than one resource and a potentially thrown exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a pointer to Parent, which points to a Child object, and Parent does not have a virtual destructor, then Child's destructor is not called. Therefore Parent needs a virtual destructor, even if it's an empty one. (Unless you guarantee this scenario will never occur).

Child does not need a destructor in your code sample. An appropriate one will be automatically generated, and it will be virtual as the parent destructor would be virtual in the fixed code.

Answer (score 2):

> The Big Question: Is there a general rule when default destructor is enough?

If you had to write a destructor for those classes, what would it do?

```
~Parent() { }

~Child() { }

~Other() { }
```

If they'd look like that, then there's no need to write it.

Comment: Then the `Parent` destructor would not look like the one above, would it?